# Drawing to canvas with user interaction is a bit laggy

Tags: android, multithreading, android-canvas, java-threads

I started to study **canvas drawing** with Android, and i would like to make a simple app.

On app start a so called 'snake' starting to move on the screen, **when the user taps the screen, the 'snake' changes direction.**

I achived this easily but there is a little issue:

When the user taps on the screen, the snake **sometimes changes direction on that particular moment, sometimes just after some milliseconds.** So the user can clearly feels that the interaction is **not as responsive as it should,** the **snake's exact moment of turning is pretty unpredictable** even if you concentrate very hard. There must be some other way to do this better than i did.

Please check my code, I use a **Handler with Runnable to move the snake.** (Drawing on a canvas and each time setting it as the background of a view, that is each time setting with setContentView to my Activity.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Canvas canvas;


    View contentView; ///<The view to set by setContentView

    int moveSize; ///<Sze in px to move drawer to draw another square


    int leftIndex; ///<Indexes for square drawing
    int topIndex;
    int rightIndex;
    int bottomIndex;

    int maxBoundsX; ///<The max number of squares in X axis
    int maxBoundsY; ///<The max number of squares in Y axis

    int moveSpeedInMillis = 25; ///<One movement square per milliseconds

    Bitmap bitmapToDrawOn; ///<We draw the squares to this bitmap

    Direction currentDirection = Direction.RIGHT; ///< RIGHT,LEFT,UP,DOWN directions. default is RIGHT

    Handler  handler  = new Handler(); ///<Handler for running a runnable that actually 'moves' the snake by drawing squares to shifted positions
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Log.i("runnable", "ran");

            //Drawing a square to the current destination
            drawRectPls(currentDirection);
            //After some delay we call again and again and again
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, moveSpeedInMillis);
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        /*getting area properties like moveSize, and bounds*/

        moveSize = searchForOptimalMoveSize();

        maxBoundsX = ScreenSizer.getScreenWidth(this) / moveSize;
        maxBoundsY = ScreenSizer.getScreenHeight(this) / moveSize;

        Log.i("moveSize", "moveSize: " + moveSize);
        Log.i("maxBounds: ", "x: " + maxBoundsX + " ; " + "y: " + maxBoundsY);


        /*setting start pos*/

        //We start on the lower left part of the screen

        leftIndex = moveSize * (-1);
        rightIndex = 0;
        bottomIndex = moveSize * maxBoundsY;
        topIndex = moveSize * (maxBoundsY - 1);


        //Setting contentView, bitmap, and canvas

        contentView = new View(this);
        contentView.setOnClickListener(this);

        bitmapToDrawOn = Bitmap.createBitmap(ScreenSizer.getScreenWidth(this), ScreenSizer.getScreenHeight(this), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmapToDrawOn);

        contentView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapToDrawOn));
        setContentView(contentView);

        /*starts drawing*/
        handler.post(runnable);


    }

    /**
     * Draws a square to the next direction
     *
     * @param direction the direction to draw the next square
     */
    private void drawRectPls(Direction direction) {

        if (direction.equals(Direction.RIGHT)) {
            leftIndex += moveSize;
            rightIndex += moveSize;
        } else if (direction.equals(Direction.UP)) {
            topIndex -= moveSize;
            bottomIndex -= moveSize;
        } else if (direction.equals(Direction.LEFT)) {
            leftIndex -= moveSize;
            rightIndex -= moveSize;
        } else if (direction.equals(Direction.DOWN)) {
            topIndex += moveSize;
            bottomIndex += moveSize;
        }


        addRectToCanvas();
        contentView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapToDrawOn));
        Log.i("drawRect", "direction: " + currentDirection);

    }


    private void addRectToCanvas() {
        paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 100, 100, 255));
        canvas.drawRect(leftIndex, topIndex, rightIndex, bottomIndex, paint);
    }

    /**
     * Upon tapping the screen the the snake is changing direction, one way simple interaction
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.equals(contentView)) {

            if (currentDirection.equals(Direction.RIGHT)) {
                currentDirection = Direction.UP;
            } else if (currentDirection.equals(Direction.UP)) {
                currentDirection = Direction.LEFT;
            } else if (currentDirection.equals(Direction.LEFT)) {
                currentDirection = Direction.DOWN;
            } else if (currentDirection.equals(Direction.DOWN)) {
                currentDirection = Direction.RIGHT;
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Just getting the size of a square. Searching for an integer that divides both screen's width and height
     * @return
     */
    private int searchForOptimalMoveSize() {
        int i;
        for (i = 16; i <= 64; i++) {
            Log.i("iter", "i= " + i);
            if (ScreenSizer.getScreenWidth(this) % i == 0) {
                Log.i("iter", ScreenSizer.getScreenWidth(this) + "%" + i + " =0 !");
                if (ScreenSizer.getScreenHeight(this) % i == 0) {
                    Log.i("iter", ScreenSizer.getScreenHeight(this) + "%" + i + " =0 !");
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }


    /**
     * Stops the handler
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}
```

**E D I T:**

I have modified my code, now the **view contains all the details** and i use the **onDraw** and **invalidate** methods just like Philipp suggested.

The result is a little better but **i can still clearly feel that the user interaction is results in a laggy direction change.**

Perhaps something i should do with threads?

```
public class SpiralView extends View implements View.OnClickListener {

    int leftIndex; ///<Indexes for square drawing
    int topIndex;
    int rightIndex;
    int bottomIndex;

    int speedInMillis = 50;

    int moveSize; ///<Sze in px to move drawer to draw another square

    int maxBoundsX; ///<The max number of squares in X axis
    int maxBoundsY; ///<The max number of squares in Y axis


    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Direction currentDirection = Direction.RIGHT; ///< RIGHT,LEFT,UP,DOWN directions. default is RIGHT


    public void setUp(int moveSize, int maxBoundsX, int maxBoundsY) {
        this.moveSize = moveSize;
        this.maxBoundsX = maxBoundsX;
        this.maxBoundsY = maxBoundsY;
        this.leftIndex = moveSize * (-1);
        this.rightIndex = 0;
        this.bottomIndex = moveSize * (maxBoundsY);
        this.topIndex = moveSize * (maxBoundsY - 1);

    }

    public SpiralView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    /**
     * Draws a square to the next direction
     *
     * @param direction the direction to draw the next square
     */
    private void drawOnPlease(Direction direction, Canvas canvas) {

        if (direction.equals(Direction.RIGHT)) {
            leftIndex += moveSize;
            rightIndex += moveSize;
        } else if (direction.equals(Direction.UP)) {
            topIndex -= moveSize;
            bottomIndex -= moveSize;
        } else if (direction.equals(Direction.LEFT)) {
            leftIndex -= moveSize;
            rightIndex -= moveSize;
        } else if (direction.equals(Direction.DOWN)) {
            topIndex += moveSize;
            bottomIndex += moveSize;
        }


        Log.i("drawRect", "direction: " + currentDirection);
        Log.i("drawRect", "indexes: "+topIndex+" , "+rightIndex+" ," +bottomIndex+" , "+leftIndex);

        addRectToCanvas(canvas);

    }

    private void addRectToCanvas(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 100, 100, 255));

       canvas.drawRect(leftIndex, topIndex, rightIndex, bottomIndex, paint);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        try {

            drawOnPlease(currentDirection, canvas);

            synchronized (this) {
                wait(speedInMillis);
            }


            invalidate();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (currentDirection.equals(Direction.RIGHT)) {
            currentDirection = Direction.UP;
        } else if (currentDirection.equals(Direction.UP)) {
            currentDirection = Direction.LEFT;
        } else if (currentDirection.equals(Direction.LEFT)) {
            currentDirection = Direction.DOWN;
        } else if (currentDirection.equals(Direction.DOWN)) {
            currentDirection = Direction.RIGHT;
        }

        //..?
        invalidate();

    }

}
```

Comment: Invalidate() inside onDraw() is a bad idea - it will cause recursive onDraw() calls. Just remove it and probably you'll be fine.

Comment: @ruan65 Then what will draw the snake periodicly?

Comment: `wait` on the ui thread is **always** a bad idea

Comment: There is always the surface view route with a dedicated rendering thread (shouldn't be needed for snake though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic number is 16 milliseconds for android to redraw the view without having framedrops.

Checkout this video from android developers wich explains this.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CaMTIgxCSqU&index=25&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE

Especially check this video
https://youtu.be/vkTn3Ule4Ps?t=54

It explains how to use canvas **clipping** in order not to draw the whole surface in every cicle, nut draw only what is needed to be draw.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a Handler to draw with Canvas.
Instead you should create a Custom View and use the onDraw(Canvas canvas) method.
In this method you can draw on the Canvas object like you already did.
By calling the invalidate() method you trigger a new onDraw() call.
In the onTouch() or onClick() function you also trigger a new onDraw call by calling invalidate()

```
class SnakView extends View {
  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // draw on canvas
    invalidate();
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // handle the event
    invalidate();
  }
}
```

Comment: And how do i "wait" in onDraw if i cannot use Handler?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and Add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to your manifest, to the  or the .

This will work for devices having 3.0+.

Also your target api level should be 11.

Then it will work more smoothly.

Comment: hardware acceleration is turned on by default starting from the Android 4, so I doubt that this will fix OP's issue.